# Textfield scroll up not working iOS

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm new to stackoverflow.

Im trying to get the UI text fields to scroll up when editing.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

 public class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


public var loginData = userModel()



@IBOutlet weak var user: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var passTextField: UITextField!






override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

override public func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    user.delegate = self
    user.returnKeyType = .done
    self.view.addSubview(user)

    passTextField.delegate = self
    passTextField.returnKeyType = .done
    self.view.addSubview(passTextField)
}


public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    user.resignFirstResponder()
    passTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


override public func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    loginData.login = user.text!


    var tabBar: SunnybrookTabBarController = segue.destination as! SunnybrookTabBarController


    tabBar.loginData = loginData




}

public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: 100)
}

public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(up: false, moveValue: 100)
}

// Lifting the view up
public func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
    let movementDuration:TimeInterval = 0.3
    let movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration )
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0,  dy: movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}







}
```

Now when I implement this, the textfields are pushed all the way to the top of the screen, before I even click on them to open up the keyboard.

[As you can see they are pushed all the way from their normal placement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctYAS.png)

Comment: I would use a ScrollView, you can call `func scrollRectToVisible(_ rect: CGRect, animated: Bool)` on your textfields whenever the keyboard is presented.  You could also use `nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyBoardDidShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
        nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyBoardDidHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)` to only run your animations on keyboard showing/hiding

Comment: BTW, you have your textfields set as IBOutlets, you shouldn't have to use `view.addSubview()` to display them from your storyboard/XiB

Comment: Hi, just removing the view.addSubview() ended up working for me.

Comment: Good!  I would still suggest using `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver()` for the `UIKeyboardDidShow` and `UIKeyboardDidHide`notifications.  This is a system notification sent for the purpose of changing the UI based around the keyboard.  Just make sure to remove the observers in your `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your views declared as @IBOutlets most probably means that they are already part of the view hierarchy.

Try removing the view.addSubview(view) from your -viewWillAppear:

This should solve your issue.